# SASS/SCSS: @use variables defined to global namespace throwing "Undefined Variable" error

Tags: sass

I'm compiling an SCSS file to CSS, using the three following files:

bootstrap/_variables.scss:

```
$font-color-root: #ff6d00;
$font-color-dark: #000;
```

themes/_theme.scss:

```
:root {
    --font-color: #{$font-color-root};
}
 
/* dark theme variables */
[data-theme=\'dark\'] { 
    --font-color: #{$font-colour-dark};
}
```

style.scss:

```
//import variables
@use 'bootstrap/variables' as *;

//import CSS files
@use 'themes/theme';
```

This keeps throwing this error, obviously the variables are not visible within the theme.scss file, how do I make them visible?

I thought that the global namespace would be the solution to this problem.

```
Error: Undefined variable.
  ╷
2 │     --font-color: #{$font-color-root};
`
```

Comment: Don't combine css variables with sass variables. Just use the sass variable. Also the # outside the css variable call is not needed and will also throw an error.

Comment: @NathanielFlick Unless I am mistaken, CSS and SASS variables perform different functions. The CSS variables are necessary for a light/dark theme. I do not see how separating those from eachother results in a functional light/dark theme CSS file. As for the #{$var} variables, this doc explains that that is necessary for CSS theme variables: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

Comment: Are you using dart-sass ?

Comment: @Arkellys yes that’s right

Comment: @JimmyBanks SASS is rendered before load time, CSS Variables can be changed after load time, so if you combine them you're limiting the power of the CSS Variables to change, they get rendered and removed when SASS is pre-processed. Your format with the additional # will also fail.

Comment: @NathanielFlick You didn't review the document I posted. That is the correct syntax and it is working for me as the docs make clear it will.

Comment: @JimmyBanks I found this article that might help you with the formatting so it will work: https://codeburst.io/magic-of-css-sass-variables-b07ae8c1b775

Comment: @NathanielFlick I've already posted the solution that uses the variables formatted as shown, and as explained in the documentation to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the solution:

Bootstrap/Main file:

```
$theme: "default";

//Import CSS file, pass the set $theme using `with ()`
@use 'themes/base_theme' with ($theme: $theme);
```

_base_theme.scss:

```
//theme will default to the value set here unless overwritten in the calling file using the `with` language construct
$theme: "default" !default;    

//gets vars with theme specified
@use '../bootstrap/variables' as vars with ($theme: $theme);

:root {
    --font-color: #{$font-color-root};
}

/* dark theme variables */
[data-theme=\'dark\'] { 
    --font-color: #{$font-colour-dark};
}
```

_variables.scss:

```
//Set Initial SCSS Variables
$theme: "default" !default;


$font-color-root: #000;
$font-color-dark: #fff;

//if theme is set to "not_default", change values
@if $theme == "not_default" {
    $font-color-root: #fff;
    $font-color-dark: #000;
}
```

To summarize: the default file calls a theme file, within the theme file, the required variables are imported using the `@use` language construct. `@use` can be coupled with `with ()` to overwrite default variable settings (in this case `$theme` can be overwritten).